# MySQL query gives null value when one of the WHERE conditions results in false

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems with a MySQL query.
I've two tables namely users and projects. I am trying to get the project name and the number of users working in a particular project. Below is the query I'm using.

```
SELECT b.projName AS project_name, 
       COUNT(a.empId) AS project_strength 
FROM users a, 
     projects b 
WHERE b.projName LIKE '%windows%' AND 
     (a.empProjId = b.projId)
```

In a case, when there are no users working for a project( there are no rows in users table where the empProjId will match with projId of projects table), I get the project name as null, even though the project exists in projects table, and the like clause matches. In such cases, I want the project name to be displayed and the count to be 0.

I'm a beginner and don't know whether it's possible or not. Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Many Thanks.

Comment: I see already a possible design problem with your database. can an employee be linked to multiple projects ? I presume yes (not necessarily running projects, but could aswell be old ones). In that case you should have a 3rd table with 2 field : projectId and userId, in order to link multiple projects to A given user, and multiple users to a given project (=many-to-many relationship). For the rest, the answers will probably help you...

Comment: @Bartdude Many thanks for your response. Yes, some of the users might be working in multiple projects. I'll keep this in mind, and do the required changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT b.projName AS project_name, 
       COUNT(a.empId) AS project_strength 
FROM projects b 
LEFT JOIN users a ON  a.empProjId = b.projId
WHERE b.projName LIKE '%windows%'
GROUP BY b.projName
```

LEFT JOIN will make sure you always get the project_name, even when there are no match in users.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a left join and a count with group by.

```
SELECT b.projName AS project_name, 
       count(b.projName) AS project_strength 
  FROM projects b LEFT JOIN 
       users a ON (b.projId = a.empProjId)
 WHERE b.projName LIKE '%windows%' 
 group by b.projName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` for such things, which forces the DB to return all relevant records from "left" side of the query (the `FROM` table), whether or not there are any matching records in the "right" side of the query (the `JOIN`ed tables):

```
SELECT b.projName AS project_name, 
       COUNT(a.empId) AS project_strength 
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN projects b  ON a.empProjId = b.projID
WHERE b.projName LIKE '%windows%'
```

The equivalent syntax for your "lazy join" version would be

```
WHERE b.projName LIKE '%windows%' AND
   ((a.empProjId = b.projId) OR (b.projID IS NULL))
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. The above worked, after I interchanged the join order. I mean `projects b LEFT JOIN users a`